# Prestashop web service - get tax and shipping cost for order

Tags: api, prestashop

I am looking to make an order using prestashop API (web service). I am reaching the end but it still miss some informations about:

- tax cost
- shipping cost

If someone knows routes or process to get these kind of informations it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a little bit old, but I managed to get those info via webservices this way:

Edited Cart.php core class (there is a more elegant way, but this works too).

```
// added 2 attributes in class
public $my_shipping_cost;
public $my_order_total;



// added some more data to $webserviceParameters
protected $webserviceParameters = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'id_address_delivery' => array('xlink_resource' => 'addresses'),
        'id_address_invoice' => array('xlink_resource' => 'addresses'),
        'id_currency' => array('xlink_resource' => 'currencies'),
        'id_customer' => array('xlink_resource' => 'customers'),
        'id_guest' => array('xlink_resource' => 'guests'),
        'id_lang' => array('xlink_resource' => 'languages'),
        'my_shipping_cost' => array(
                            'getter' => 'getMyShippingCost',
                            'setter' => 'getMyShippingCost'
                    ),
        'my_order_total' => array(
                            'getter' => 'getMyOrderTotal',
                            'setter' => 'getMyOrderTotal',
                    ),

    ), ...

// added some methods to process the values
public function getMyShippingCost(){
    if (!isset($this->my_shipping_cost))
        $this->setMyCustomFieldsValues();
    return $this->my_shipping_cost;
}

public function getMyOrderTotal(){
    if (!isset($this->my_order_total))
                    $this->setMyCustomFieldsValues();
            return $this->my_order_total;

}

public function setMyCustomFieldsValues(){

    if (!isset($this->id))
        return;

    $currency = 1;
    $taxCalculationMethod = Group::getPriceDisplayMethod((int)Group::getCurrent()->id);
    $useTax = !($taxCalculationMethod == PS_TAX_EXC);

    $base_shipping = $this->getOrderTotal($useTax, Cart::ONLY_SHIPPING, null, $this->id_carrier, false);
    $this->my_shipping_cost = $base_shipping;
    $this->my_order_total = $this->getOrderTotal($useTax, Cart::BOTH, null, $this->id_carrier, false);

}
```

Maybe you can improve some of the code, but this is some way to go.

Best,
Eder.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but about shipping cost I think it is in the function :

```
public function getOrderShippingCost($params, $shipping_cost) {
// This example returns shipping cost with overcost set in the back-office, but you can call a webservice or calculate what you want before returning the final value to the Cart
        if ($this->id_carrier == (int)(Configuration::get('MYCARRIER1_CARRIER_ID')) && Configuration::get('MYCARRIER1_OVERCOST') > 1)
            return (float)(Configuration::get('MYCARRIER1_OVERCOST'));
        if ($this->id_carrier == (int)(Configuration::get('MYCARRIER2_CARRIER_ID')) && Configuration::get('MYCARRIER2_OVERCOST') > 1)
            return (float)(Configuration::get('MYCARRIER2_OVERCOST'));

        // If the carrier is not known, you can return false, the carrier won't appear in the order process
        return false;
}
```

However it is used in CarrierModule, what kind of module are you creating ?

Comment: I am working on an iOS application and I am using the web service to make an order, create users...

Comment: Use this :    $this->context->order->***     instead of *** look in the database, table ps_orders, the value you want to get. I dont remember but it could be tax_cost and shipping_cost